# Use email addresses collected on a SFMC CloudPage to update/create Contacts (etc) in Sales Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, cloudpage

I've created a CloudPage in Marketing Cloud, to collect email address and some other information. I thought I would be able to use the DE as entry DE for Journey Builder, use the email address to check if an account/contact exists for it in Sales Cloud, and if not, create a new one. But the entry DE needs to be sendable (I believe that wasn't the case before), and I can't make it sendable unless I have an email address (have that) and a Subscriber Key (do not have that).

Ideally I don't want to do the account/contact creation directly in Sales Cloud from the CloudPage, because I've tried that in the past and the performance was downright terrible sometimes. And I also don't want to create duplicate records, so while I could just use Email as SubscriberKey, I don't want to do that either.

What is a nice way to do this, that doesn't require communicating with Sales Cloud directly from the CloudPage?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you wish to enter a person into a journey if the email address they submit in a form is not in the system already.
Also, if the submitted email address is new you want to generate a new subscriber key.

If this is correct, you will need to do a lookup on this email address wherever it is located. If the email address is only located in sales cloud you can use this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud-ampscript/references/mc-ampscript-salesforce/mc-ampscript-reference-salesforce-retrieve-objects.html

if the email address is located in marketing cloud, you can use this:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud-ampscript/references/mc-ampscript-data-extension/mc-ampscript-reference-data-extension-lookup-rows.html

Combine this with a simple if statement and generate a new ID if new, then you should have all you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to enter everyone in a journey, and ideally without Ampscript that communicates with Sales Cloud, because I've seen bad performance from that in the past, so I thought I would do it later/in the background/asynchronous.

I did learn in the meanwhile that we store form submissions as a custom Sales Event object in Sales Cloud, which creates or updates Accounts/Contacts/Leads automatically. So for now I think the minimum of Ampscript I'll have to use is one CreateSalesforceObject post. I should then be able to trigger a Journey on the Sales Event record creation.

Comment: It sounds like you have solved the issue. If not, please try to rephrase the question, so I can understand it better with the new information.